# How to get a boto3 STS client without any authentication attempt?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I'm using this code to assume an Amazon Web Services role via SAML authentication:

```
client = boto3.client('sts', region_name = region)
token = client.assume_role_with_saml(role, principal, saml)
```

As documented [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role_with_saml), the `assume_role_with_saml` call *does not require the use of AWS security credentials*; all the auth info is contained in the parameters to the call itself. Nonetheless, if I have auth-related `AWS_` environment variables set, the call to `boto3.client()` immediately tries to use them to authenticate. Usually, I have `AWS_PROFILE` set, and the reason I'm running this code is because the named profile's security token has expired, so the call fails, and I have to unset `AWS_PROFILE` and try again.

I can of course manually go through `os.environ` looking for and deleting relevant variables before the call to `boto3.client()`, but I'm wondering if there's any cleaner way to say "Hey, Boto, just give me an STS client object without trying to authenticate anything, OK?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this response on GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1200#issuecomment-319141394), here's how to set up a client that won't attempt to sign outgoing requests with IAM credentials:

```
import boto3                      
from botocore import UNSIGNED     
from botocore.config import Config

client = boto3.client('sts', region_name=region, config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
```

Answer (score 0):

By examining the boto3 and botocore code, I worked out a solution, but I'm not sure it's an improvement over unsetting the environment variables:

```
import boto3, botocore
bs = botocore.session.get_session({ 'profile': ( None, ['', ''], None, None ) })
bs.set_credentials('','','')
s = boto3.session.Session(botocore_session = bs)
client = s.client('sts', region_name = region)
```

Accepting my own answer for now, but if anyone has a better idea, I'm all ears.